# Dual-boot question involving separate HD and windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I use an external HD with Ubuntu+GRUB on it. This allows me to effectively "hijack" most systems. Basically it's a permanent LiveUSB - my own system wherever I go. I use it for recovery mainly when Windows systems muck up, and for portability (as I can have my system on the go, without effecting the pc I'm borrowing, much like a LiveCD).

I'm about to update to Windows 8 now [on a new, different computer]. Is there any special measure I should take to do this?

I've seen a similar post here, but the OP had both harddrives plugged in simultaneously - that's not exactly my setup.

Thank you :)

EDIT: added for clarification that this is for a totally new computer.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, since you're using the same computer, you'll have no trouble at all.

Now, if you were upgrading to a new computer, it would be a bit more tricky.  But all you would have to do is enable booting non-secure devices in the BIOS.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to do, I phrased it poorly. New laptop coming on Wed, would like to put win 8 on it, and still retain Ubuntu on-demand accessibility without having to muck around with UEFI every time.

From your answer, it seems a simple bios-tweak should make this feature available. Thanks :)

edit1: I'll toggle the answer thing in 48 hrs, in case someone has some different input that might also be worth hearing.